# Oracle - datatype to store number of a specific length

Tags: sql, oracle, types, sqldatatypes

I'm trying to figure out what datatype I should use in my database to store a fixed 8 digits number.

Should I use `char(8)` even though it accepts other characters and validate on the application side or there is something like `number(x)` that could make it ?

I've got the same dilemma with the phone number column. Should I use `char(x)` or something would be more appropriate ?

Edit - Answers to your questions:

1. the first fixed 8 digits column will most likely be used as a primary key. It represents to social security number in my country. No arithmetic will be done on this column. I need to keep all digits (even possible leading zeros). Although, it will probably sorted (since it'll be a primary key)
2. For the phone number I was going to store it as a string like this : `12345678901`. The question was more about "How can I make sure that this `char[]` will not accept letters or other characters. Should this validation be made client-side ?

Comment: How will you use that value?  Will it just be a string of digits, like an account number? Or will you actually do any mathematical manipulations?  Can you guarantee that you'll  ever need more characters, or to use alphabetic characters too?  Etc, etc...

Comment: As for a phone number, use characters.  The leading 0 is important, you can include () and + characters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends.

Is it a number? Will you do mathemtical operations on the number? Will you sort it numerically? If yes, then store it as a number. You should also create a constraint to ensure that the number always has 8 digits:

```
number_field number(8) check (number_field between 11111111 and 99999999)
```

If it's more like a code (like a credit card number, social security number or account number), I think I would use char(8), and a check constraint to ensure that it contains only numbers (a regular expression is a very good use for this). By using a char datatype rather than a varchar you don't need to make sure that the field contains 8 characters, just that the characters are all digits.

```
code_field char(8) check (regexp_like(code_field, '[:digit:]{8}'))
```

In effect, what you want are *domains* but Oracle doesn't have them.

As to whether to validate client-side or server-side, in my world, I always rely on database constraints to ensure that the data stored in the database is as clean as possible. In my apps, I test for constraint violation to return an appropriate error to the user. Of course, you can do validation client-side too, but why repeat yourself? The only case is when you want to avoid a round trip to the server.

Comment: Why check twice?  Belt and bracers and simpler user feedback.  +1, nice answer.

Comment: Yeah, I mostly do just once, just with eg mobile apps you want to avoid a slow round trip altogether if you can check it client side first anyway. But using MDD techniques we can generate necessary client side validation code.

Answer (score 0):

You should always use numeric data type to store numbers, if you intend to use them for mathematical operations. So use `NUMBER` and sure you can specify it's length by using NUMBER(8) but be sure you'll never use a longer number.

More on [Oracle Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/datatype.htm#i16209).

As for the Phone number, it's always better to store it as a `CHAR(11)`. I recommend you remove any useless caracter before storing it, and by the same time insuring uniformity of your data.

So "1 (888) 673-1234" would be stored as "18886731234" in your table.

Comment: IMHO, you don't always store numbers in numeric data types, see @Dems first comment

Comment: You say to ***always*** store numeric data as a numeric type.  Then you show that you dont do that for phone numbers, even when you strip out all non-numeric characters?

Comment: @Dems: I misread his question and interpreted 2 questions, one about storing numbers (for mathematical use) and the other about storing numbers (for non-mathematical use). My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Use char(8) if you are not doing any numeric operation or using as primary key where as you can use number(8) : if using number(8) datatype and storing 1234 it will store only 4 digit which need to be formatted to display as 8 digit.

Answer (score -1):

Use a numeric type such as int.

Comment: Please supply more details. A one-liner will likely be deleted.

Comment: you want a better answer ask a better question. You store numbers using numeric data types, period.

Comment: Except when it's not a number. I wouldn't store a phone number in a numeric field.